# change in phpmyadmin 3.3.9 config file not giving me access to phpmyadmin

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, config, wampserver

I'm working on a legacy system that uses phpmyadmin 3.3.9, and ALL I did to the config.inc.php file was to change    `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` to `false`. Next thing I know, I get this error:

```
MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Then I tried to revert back but no matter what I do, it doesn't connect. I replaced the config file by a config file from a mirror system but no luck! This is the config file contents, what's gone wrong?

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

The application is able to access mysql fine, the issue is in accessing the web interface of phpmyadmin.

I almost feel like it's an error similar to how a file edited on windows and unix might have issues only because of the difference in newline character, because all I did was change one word and save it. But I'm working entirely in Windows.

I tried changing `auth_type` from `config` to `http` as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just restarted all WAMP services and then it ran fine! I thought of deleting this question but then figured it might just be useful for someone who's tearing their hair but have forgotten to simply restart.